# Idiomatic way of converting from Long object to long primitive safely in java

Tags: java

I was trying to pass a Long object value to a method that expects long primitive, passing directly works except for the case when the Long object is null. In this case I get a Null Pointer Exception.

```
Long foo=null;
bar.methodExpects_long_primitive(foo);
```

I can create a check if foo is null and skip calling the method, like

```
Long foo=null;
if(foo!=null){
bar.methodExpects_long_primitive(foo);
}
```

or if I want to provide a default value

```
Long foo=null;
bar.methodExpects_long_primitive(foo==null?defaultValue:foo);
```

Is there a elegant/better way to do this? I have to repeat this multiple times in the codebase and doing it like this seems to add a lot of conditionals.

I could create my own method to do this, but I would like to know if there is already any such library method.

Comment: You said you're passing a *primitive*, then you say "except for the case when the **long object**...".

Comment: @MarounMaroun: The starting pont is a `Long` variable; the method accepts a `long` primitive. Goal is to avoid an NPE when the `Long` is `null` , thus not just using auto-unboxing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As of Java 8**, one option is to wrap your Long in an [java.util.Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). Wherever possible, pass this around instead of the Long. When you must get a long value, you can provide a default with `Optional.orElse()`:

```
Long foo = null;

Optional<Long> optFoo = Optional.ofNullable( foo );
long longFoo = optFoo.orElse( -1L );

System.out.println( longFoo );
```

Or you can test whether the Optional holds a value with `Optional.empty()`:

```
    Long foo = null;

    Optional<Long> optFoo = Optional.ofNullable( foo );
    if ( ! optFoo.empty() ) {
        long longFoo = optFoo.get();

        System.out.println( longFoo );
    }
```

One nice side effect of this approach is that it is clear that the value might be null, no matter where you pass the Optional. Another is that an attempt to call get() when the value is null will throw an exception immediately.

**Before Java 8,** you could use Google's guava library, which provides a very similar class [com.google.common.base.Optional](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Optional.html).

Comment: I wondered if there might be something like that in the "new" (from my perspective) stuff.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Before Java 8, there was Guava's very similar Optional class. I used Guava's version until we updated. I should have mentioned that above; adding now.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing built into `Long` (e.g., some static method) to do it.

Assuming you have multiple methods accepting `long` you need to use this with, you'll probably want your own method, something along the lines of

```
// On some utility class, say LongUtil
public static long val(Long l, long defaultvalue) {
    return l == null ? defaultValue : l.longValue();
}
```

Then

```
bar.methodExpects_long_primitive(LongUtil.val(foo, defaultValue));
```

Of course, that's not a lot shorter than

```
bar.methodExpects_long_primitive(foo == null ? defaultValue : (long)foo);
```

If it's just `methodExpects_long_primitive`, I'd probably modify it to accept a `Long` instead, and handle the `null` within it.

Comment: Hey, thanks this is exactly what I was thinking of! But I am not sure if there is any library that already provided the functionality.

Comment: @DhairyaSeth: There may be some *library* that does (I don't happen to know of one), but library requests are off-topic for Stack Overflow. :-) I'm fairly certain the JDK doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

just change your method to get object Long and then check for null

```
T methodExpects_long_primitive(Long l) {
    long foo = (l != null) ? l : 0L;
```

If you do not owe the method you need to handle null out of the method as you wrote

```
bar.methodExpects_long_primitive(foo==null?defaultValue:foo);
```

Comment: This approach can be used if there is only a single method but I have multiple methods like this in my code and repeating this everywhere would appear a bit odd. I would have preferred a Library implementation to do this, as an alternate I think T.J. Crowder's implementation would suit perfectly for my need. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Seems not to be more odd than wrapping every call with NPE check :)